# checking user input via textfield

Tags: cocoa, fast-enumeration

I've been struggling with this for quite a few days now; my app has a diagram with uitextfields to represent labelling of the picture. I would like to check the user input against a dictionary (for the answer) and if it is correct, increase the score by 1.
I had it working by 'hard coding' each of the textfield.text queries each with their own if statement, but I would like a better and more reusable way if possible?
I've tried this so far:

```
- (IBAction)checkAnswers:(UITextField *)textField
{
// array for each textfield
allTextfields = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:eyepiece, objectiveLenses, focussingKnobs, stage, mirror, nil];
// array for each UIImageView
allTicks = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:eyepieceTick, objectiveTick, focussingTick, stageTick, mirrorTick, nil];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tick.png"];

for (textField in allTextfields) {

    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:[[microscopeBrain.microscopeDictionary valueForKey:theTextfieldTag] valueForKey:@"Answer"]]) {
        [[allTicks objectAtIndex:textField.tag] setImage:image];
        x++;
      textField.enabled = NO;
       NSLog(@"%@", microscopeBrain.microscopeDictionary);
    //    NSLog(@"%@", [[microscopeBrain.microscopeDictionary valueForKey:theTextfieldTag] valueForKey:@"Answer"]);
    }

    finalMicroscopeScore = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", x];
    microscopeScoreLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", x];

    }
    }
```

The problem is that even if the answers are in the wrong textfield, as long as one is correct, they will all show up as right, which is kind of embarrassing!
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is "theTextFieldTag" -- it looks like you're checking the same value in the dictionary each time though the loop. It would help if you would post the microscopeDictionary (or a piece of it) so we could see the structure.

Comment: Thank you again @rdelmar, you keep bailing me out! TheTextFieldTag is a string representation of the 'currently editing' textfield's tag.  I have them from 0 to 4 (for the 5 textfields) and the dictionary is set up with the initial keys being 0 to 4, then an "answer" key within that to check against.  I think the problem is that it is cycling through all of the possible correct answers for all of the textfields somehow because there's no problem with random 'wrong' answers.

Comment: To clarify, if I put in "dog", it won't give the mark but if I put "eyepiece" which is correct in to all of the boxes, it will say it's correct.  Or "stage" or any other of the correct answers.  As long as one is correct, it will mark the others correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the valueForKey:theTextFieldTag to valueForKey:textField.tag and  see if that helps.  You don't show how you get the value for theTextFieldTag, so I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll give that a try later.  I use NSString *theTextfieldTag = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", textfield.tag];  I believe but if it's anything different, I'll repost :)  Thanks again

Comment: Textfield.tag gives an error because it's an integer I believe, which is why I wrapped it (is that the word?) in an nsstring as above. I put an nslog into the loop and it's giving 5 instances of 0, 5 of 1 all the way up to 4 which is why I think it's going through the whole dictionary as opposed to specific ones

Comment: Perhaps I should use nsenumerator instead? So confused!

Comment: Sorry about that, the keys do have to be strings. You should use valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",textField.tag] to convert the integer to a string. Using an enumerator wouldn't help

Comment: Your argument for the checkAnswers method and your variable in your for-in loop are the same, and I don't know if this could cause problems.  You might want to change the for-in variable to something else and see if that helps.

Comment: OMG I've just figured it out @rdelmar, turns out I didn't even need the for in loop because the argument meant it checked all of the textfields anyway!  I thank you for your time and effort. Cheers mate